# What causes Visual Studio error CS0518 (UWP app)?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

Most of the time I try to build a release version of my application (Publish -> Create App Packages -> Sideloading), the build fails with a whole long list of errors that look like this:

error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported

I have no problem at all running the application in debug mode, either before or after this happens.

By hours of sheer trial and error, I discovered that the only sure way to clear this error is to go into my project properties and change the Windows target setting to a different version of Windows, then wait for that to take effect, and then change it back. This has become tedious.

Why am I getting this error? Is there a more permanent fix?

Frank

Comment: I should add that sometimes rebooting my computer fixes it too. But, just closing and re-opening Visual Studio does not.

Comment: might help to list the version of windows that you are targeting, also the configuration of other local dependencies. This can be caused by a mismatch when a dependent project is either not compiling, or compiles with a different target runtime version. Also try switching the publish profile.

Comment: Both Target and Min version are set to Windows 10, version 1809, build 17763.

Comment: What is a publish profile and where do I find it? I doubt my project has this. Also, it would not explain the transient nature of the problem.

Comment: This is not a _publishing_ issue per-se, just a compiler issue. Change the dropdown box that switches between _Debug_ and _Release_ to `Release` and check the output logs, in fact it might help to post the output (in a code block please) then we can give you definitive advice. Showing the output for a debug build might help, usually these types of issues are simple references that are incorrect.

Comment: The transient nature occurs because we generally develop in _Debug_ configuration, but _publishing_ will use _Release_. After a restart your VS will switch back to `Debug`